# Kafka Connect Api - Getting Started?

Tags: apache-kafka

I would like to understand the development life-cycle for Kafka connect modules.

Following http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#connect, I would like to write a custom Kafka connect module using the "connect api" but I dont know where to start. Are there any minimal examples of how to do this? Project setup etc?

Incidentally I built this one https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc and tried to run it (on google cloud) but i find errors - clearly a missing dependency but I dont know what to add. Of course it might be that this is only supposed to run on confluent platform. If it could run elsewhere then great. But if it cant, I would like to know how to build one from scratch hence my question.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef$Recommender
    at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector.start(JdbcSourceConnector.java:66)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.addConnector(Worker.java:186)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.startConnector(StandaloneHerder.java:197)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.standalone.StandaloneHerder.putConnectorConfig(StandaloneHerder.java:145)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:85) 

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef$Recommender
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause of this kind of errors is the configuration of your CLASSPATH. For Kafka Connect to find your classes on runtime you need to include them on your classpath. The following text is taken directly from the [documentation of Kafka connect](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/userguide.html) :

> All that is required to install a new plugin is to place it in the CLASSPATH of the Kafka Connect process. All the scripts for running Kafka Connect will use the CLASSPATH environment variable if it is set when they are invoked, making it easy to run with additional connector plugins:

And how to do it:
`export CLASSPATH=/path/to/my/connectors/*
bin/connect-standalone standalone.properties new-custom-connector.properties`

I have also written a [how to guide for Kafka Connect](https://cpardalis.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/how-to-get-started-with-kafka-connect-a-guide-for-a-mixpanel-connector/) that you might find helpful.

Comment: yes, i had read the docs and i had set the classpath but I am still facing issues. I guessed perhaps it was more to do with not including the right dependencies in the first place. Your guide looks very useful, thanks for that - this is the sort of information i was seeking.

Comment: can you confirm that it is possible to deploy that JDBC connector on a virgin system with only ZOOKEEPER&KAFKA and the locally built JAR or are there other things to worry about?

Comment: you also need to run the Schema Registry. The JDBC connector is using the Schema Registry to register the schema of the database and track changes to it, e.g. deletion of a table etc. The best thing to do if you want to experiment with Kafka Connect is to download the distribution from Confluent. Check the guide [here](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.1/quickstart.html#quickstart). You need to have up and running: 1) Zookeeper, 2) Kafka & 3) Schema Registry

Comment: I noticed in the docs that schema registry might be required but thought perhaps it would fallback to some default behaviour without it - i think i got this notion from scanning through the "copycat" code/docs. Anyway, thanks for your advice, very useful!

Comment: I don't think you can use the JDBC connector without the Schema Registry. In general if you want a "default" behaviour you use a STRING_SCHEMA where you just pack your data as a string inside your Kafka messages. I'm glad that I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `kafka-clients.jar` to `kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar`. The old version doesn't include this class: `org/apache/kafka/common/config/ConfigDef$Recommender.class`

You can download it here:
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.0.0/kafka-clients-0.10.0.0.jar

Answer (score -1):

Would have added this as a comment, but SO indicated that I had insufficient points.  Anyway, the point of this answer is to demonstrate that the JDBC Connector can run without installing the entire Confluent package and schema registry.

I was able to get Confluent's JDBC connector running with without installing the Confluent platform (specifically, the schema registry).  There are four Confluent libraries that you need in the classpath when you run the connector (common-config, common-metrics, common-utils and kafka-connect).  For more detailed instructions, please see https://prefrontaldump.wordpress.com/2016/05/02/using-confluents-jdbc-connector-without-installing-the-entire-platform/

Comment: Interesting. Thanks!